# What was the vulnerability in v0.3.4 that allowed an attacker to steal coins?

Tags: bitcoin-core, cve-2010-5141

Reference: http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2010-5141

What was the specific exploit in the Tx script evaluation process?

Answer (score 1):

Explanation by Mike Hearn:
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=152470.msg1620493#msg1620493

> When Bitcoin was first released, it contained two completely fatal
>   bugs that made the entire system worthless. Fortunately, they were
>   found and fixed before Bitcoin  actually had any serious value.
>
> The first bug was that scripts were concatenated before being run
>   instead of just using a shared stack. This meant that anyone could
>   write a scriptSig that always evaluated to true and claim anyone elses
>   coins. Fixed here in v0.3.2:
>
> https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/73aa262647ff9948eaf95e83236ec323347e95d0

...

> Needless to say, if somebody when this version was first released
>   actually wrote such a scriptSig and stole some coins, that would have
>   caused a chain split between old and new versions. Nobody did because,
>   why bother? I'm not even sure Mt Gox existed back then, iirc that came
>   some months later. Many script opcodes were disabled around this time
>   (which is also a hard-forking change).

Comment: So like the scriptsig "1 1 OP_EQUALVERIFY" could sign and obtain a Tx output?

Comment: I'm a little unclear on how this could lead to someone stealing coins. Could you give an example scriptSig?

Comment: @NickODell you could do things like push 0x{size of scriptPubKey} and then the execution would basically just involve pushing the serialized scriptPubKey on the stack, which would evaluate to true. Alternatively, a scriptSig of OP_TRUE OP_RETURN used to be able to spend any coins, before op return was changed to mean automatic failure.